# Installation process loops and jump to select language

Tags: boot, server, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.03 LTS server. The installation processes are weird to me. After I select a language, the installer screen will jump to installer main menu. But no matter which options I select, the menu will go to "select a language". The installation processes will never begin. Besides, the only place I can go is entering a busybox shell. I can't load any installer components. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, this issue happened when using a remote controller to control the installation of ubuntu. According to my own test, the issue is related to the java-based remote controller. It can be solved by re-opening the java-based remote controller window. Still don't know what cause this issue. But it has nothing to do with Ubuntu.